# Postgres slow performance when order is added

Tags: postgresql

I have this simple setup with a single table where I import some users having a short description (bio) that is max 255 characters. Next to the description field I have another field of type `tsvector` which is the bio but tokenized.

My goal is to find user bios that contain certain keywords. A full text search on a single table so I'm not sure if the `tsvector` field is even needed (I'm new to postgres, used only Mysql in the past) since it seems to me it gets really powerful when querying in different fields/tables.

My actual problem is the fact that this query runs ok when no ordering is involved (0.5s) but extremely slow when a single order by clause is added on an indexed field (8s). I only have about 1 million records in there.

Table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE public.django_user
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('django_user_id_seq'::regclass),
    username character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description_tokens tsvector,
    streams_count integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT django_user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT django_user_streams_count_check CHECK (streams_count >= 0)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX django_user_description_tokens_07422d46
    ON public.django_user USING btree
    (description_tokens)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX django_user_streams_count_66aa1edc
    ON public.django_user USING btree
    (streams_count)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The slow query:

```
SELECT 
    streams_count, username, description
FROM
    "django_user" 
WHERE 
    to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(("django_user"."description_tokens")::text, '')) @@ (plainto_tsquery('english'::regconfig, 'react redux')) = true 
ORDER BY streams_count ASC LIMIT 20
```

If I remove the `ORDER BY streams_count ASC` everything works fine. Here's an explain for the query:

```
"Limit  (cost=174377.42..174379.75 rows=20 width=106) (actual time=7363.660..7368.257 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=174377.42..174379.99 rows=22 width=106) (actual time=7363.658..7368.245 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=173377.40..173377.42 rows=11 width=106) (actual time=7359.708..7359.710 rows=15 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: streams_count"
"              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 31kB"
"              Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB"
"              Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on django_user  (cost=0.00..173377.21 rows=11 width=106) (actual time=24.870..7359.379 rows=109 loops=3)"
"                    Filter: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE((description_tokens)::text, ''::text)) @@ '''react'' & ''redux'''::tsquery)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 347231"
"Planning Time: 0.298 ms"
"Execution Time: 7368.293 ms"
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: That is the plan with the order by right? And the other one? Without the order by?

Comment: `Rows Removed by Filter: 347231` seems to be the performance killer here. 2: `CREATE INDEX django_user_description_tokens_07422d46
    ON public.django_user USING btree` A btree index doesn't work for tsvector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A btree index on a tsvector is pretty useless.  Make it to a GIN index, so that the query can make use of it with the @@ operator.

As for why the ORDER BY makes is slower, consider how much harder it would be find the 20 tallest people in Chicago wearing red ties, versus 20 random people in Chicago wearing red ties.